# Hide linking errors when syntax errors are present

Tags: dsl, xtext

Syntax errors in a model might cause false linking errors because the referenced element cannot be parsed. These false linking errors distract the user and makes it very hard to diagnose the root cause. What we want is to hide XtextLinkingDiagnostic when XtextSyntaxDiagnostic is present in the model, once the syntax errors are fixed the linking errors should be displayed as usual.

I didn’t find any standard way to do it in the Xtext documentation. Thus, I went ahead and implemented a custom IAcceptor in [ResourceValidatorImpl](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext/src/org/eclipse/xtext/validation/ResourceValidatorImpl.java)#createAcceptor() which removes linking errors from the list if it contains syntax errors. It works well, but I wonder if there is a standard/better way to do it than overriding ResourceValidator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about displaying linking problems as warnings instead of errors. Your syntax errors will remain red and easy to find in the ressource, whereas linking errors will be in yellow as they are less important problems.

You only have to bind a custom LinkingDiagnosticMessageProvider:

```
public Class<? extends ILinkingDiagnosticMessageProvider> bindILinkingDiagnosticMessageProvider() {
    return CustomLinkingDiagnosticMessageProvider.class;
}
```

Then you can implement it like this:

```
public class CustomLinkingDiagnosticMessageProvider extends LinkingDiagnosticMessageProvider {
    @Override
    public DiagnosticMessage getUnresolvedProxyMessage(ILinkingDiagnosticContext context) {
        DiagnosticMessage diagnosticMessage = super.getUnresolvedProxyMessage(context);
        return new DiagnosticMessage(diagnosticMessage.getMessage(),
                Severity.WARNING,
                diagnosticMessage.getIssueCode(),
                diagnosticMessage.getIssueData());
    }
}
```